# Can't find the error in while loop?

Tags: c++, debugging, while-loop

I've set up a while loop that filters out bad input. I'm inputting numbers for which the condition for the first while loop is false, 2 and 35, yet it's printing "Please input two *positive* integers" to screen. It shouldn't be, and I can't find my error. Sorry if this is a dumb question, very new beginner. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

This is what prints to screen:

Enter range to test for primes. Enter two positive integers, the smaller first, separated by whitespace.

2

35

Please input two *positive* integers.

```
//Input range
cout << "Enter range to test for primes. Enter two positive integers, the smaller first, separated by whitespace.\n";
cin >> range_min >> range_max;
cout << range_min << range_max;

//Check if input is valid.
while (range_min < 0)
{
    cout << "Please input two *positive* integers.\n";
    cin >> range_min >> range_max;
    while (range_max < 0)
    {
        cout << "Please input two *positive* integers.***\n";
        cin >> range_min >> range_max;
        while (range_min > range_max)
        {
            cout << "Please input the smaller integer first.\n";
            cin >> range_min >> range_max;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you run the code in a debugger? What did it show was the value of your variables such as range_max

Comment: I just added a memory check after the initial input, but it doesn't print that screen. I don't think it's taking in the input at all.

Comment: did you run it under a debbuger - what platform are you on?

Comment: _"I just added a memory check after the initial input ..."_ You were asked about the anomalies observed when stepping through your code line by line with a debugger, not putting a _"memory check"_ (WTH this should be). `std::cin` could be in failed state because of invalid input as well.

Comment: This is literally my second day so I have no clue how to operate a debugger. I've been having it print to screen the values of the variables in place of the debugger until I can learn. I'm on Eclipse

Comment: *This is literally my second day so I have no clue how to operate a debugger*.  Well, take a break, read up on debuggers.  Searching the internet for "Eclipse c++ debugger tutorial" should yield some good reading.

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit by adding another expression in the `while` statement:

```
while ((range_min < 0) || (range_max < 0))
{
  cout << "Please enter positive range values: ";
  cin >> range_min >> range_max;
}
```

The "||" means logical OR.  It is read as *while range_min < 0 OR range_max < 0*.

Answer (score 0):

True, the construct as you use it will also accept the values 3 and -1 as legal range as the outer while loop just checks the range_min value. If the range_min is 3 and thus greater than 0 the while loop will not execute.

So there are a few cases in which you want the user to enter new values:

1) One of the two is negativ or both

2) Both are positive but equal or range_min is greater than range_max

```
 while ((range_min < 0 || range_max <= 0) || ((range_min>0 && range_max>0) && (range_min-range_max)<=0 )) {
    cout << "Invalid range! Enter two new values: ";
    cin >> range_min >> range_max;
}
```

But ok, this still does not explain the reason for the behavior as you described. 
I compiled your code and didn't notice such a behavior. The first question would be if this is a reproducable "error"? Does it always remain the same for these two numbers?